# Как передать данные из одной формы в другую

Tags: c#, winforms

из формы GamePvP надо передать значение переменной win(false или true) в форму Winner

GamePvP :

```
…

 private bool win;
        public bool Win 
        {
            get
            {
                return win;
            }
            set
            {
                win = value;
            }
        }

…

if(deathCount == 20)
                {
                    win = true;
                    this.Close();
                    Winner winner = new Winner();
                    winner.Show();
                } else if(deathCount2 == 20)
                {
                    win = false;
                    this.Close();
                    Winner winner = new Winner();
                    winner.Show();
                }
```

Winner :

```
 public partial class Winner : Form
    {
        GamePvP gamePvP;

        public Winner()
        {
            GamePvP gamePvP = new GamePvP();
            InitializeComponent();
            player1Win.Hide();
            player2win.Hide();
            if (gamePvP.Win == true)
            {
               player1Win.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                player2win.Show();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте свойство такое же свойство в форме Winner(), только в сеттере можете добавить логики либо добавьте конструктор Winner(bool win)

Comment: Можно код сразу пожалуйста, не знаю , всё перепробовал